# Finding next occurence of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For a reason which escapes me I am not hiding and showing the div following a button click.

When I had my Buttons outside the paragraph - it worked, so I guess I am somehow not finding the following div.  I have tried .find(".divNotes").next , but that did not work either.

So I expect I have missed some simple syntax / logic

```
.article { width: 200px; }
.btnNotes { }
.divNotes { display : none; }
```

```html
<div class="article">
    <p>Text text Art 1  ... <button type="button" class="btnNotes" >Notes</button></p>
    <div class="divNotes">
        <p>Text text More 1</p>
        <p>Text text</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="article">
    <p>Text text Art 2  ... <button type="button" class="btnNotes" >Notes</button></p>

    <div class="divNotes">
        <p>Text text More 2</p>
        <p>Text text</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="article">
    <p>Text text Art 3  ...  <button type="button" class="btnNotes" >Notes</button></p>

    <div class="divNotes">
        <p>Text text More 3</p>
        <p>Text text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btnNotes').click(function(){
        if ($(this).text() === "Notes") {
            alert("Notes= " + $(this).text() + $(this).nextAll("div.divNotes").text());

            $(this).text("Less");
            $(this).nextAll("div.divNotes").toggle();          
        } else {
            alert ("Less= " + $(this).text() + $(this).nextAll("div.divNotes").text());

            $(this).text("Notes");
            $(this).nextAll("div.divNotes").toggle();
        }        
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `button` is not a sibling of `.divNotes`, hence `nextAll()` or `next()` will not find anything. You could fix this by using `closest()` to get the parent `.article` and usnig `find()` to get the required div, like this:

```
$('.btnNotes').click(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text() === "Notes" ? 'Less' : "Notes")
        .closest('.article').find('.divNotes').toggle();
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/8gp78jb8/)

Note the use of a ternary expression to simplify the logic over the expanded `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you all for your solutions - it was as I suspected a 'parent' issue and I am much clearer about the hierarchy.  I like this answer best, because it does not use 'parent' and calculating the levels, but references a specific HTML element, which is a starting point for the find.  I thought closest went up the DOM - my mistake.  I am also quite taken by the brevity of the answer.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Also, you're correct in that `closest()` does go up the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

`nextAll()` traverse the siblings which are next to it. But in `p` tag , button is the only sibling, it cannot find `divNotes` So you need to use `.parent()` to actually use `.nextAll()`

```
  $(this).parent().nextAll("div.divNotes").toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by adding .parent() to your line $(this).parent().nextAll(".divNotes").toggle();

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btnNotes').click(function(){
        if ($(this).text() === "Notes") {
            alert("Notes= " + $(this).text() + $(this).nextAll(".divNotes").text());

            $(this).text("Less");
            $(this).parent().nextAll(".divNotes").toggle();          
        } else {
            alert ("Less= " + $(this).text() + $(this).nextAll("div.divNotes").text());

            $(this).text("Notes");
            $(this).parent().nextAll(".divNotes").toggle();
        }

    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the parent `div.article` from the button click and toggle it's corresponding `div.divNotes`.

**Here is a working example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btnNotes').click(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === "Notes") {
      $(this).text("Less");
    } else {
      $(this).text("Notes");
    }
    $(this).parents("div.article").find("div.divNotes").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.article {
  width: 200px;
}
.btnNotes {} .divNotes {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="article">
  <p>Text text Art 1 ...
    <button type="button" class="btnNotes">Notes</button>
  </p>
  <div class="divNotes">
    <p>Text text More 1</p>
    <p>Text text</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="article">
  <p>Text text Art 2 ...
    <button type="button" class="btnNotes">Notes</button>
  </p>

  <div class="divNotes">
    <p>Text text More 2</p>
    <p>Text text</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="article">
  <p>Text text Art 3 ...
    <button type="button" class="btnNotes">Notes</button>
  </p>

  <div class="divNotes">
    <p>Text text More 3</p>
    <p>Text text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find next all div with particular class and you want to toggle that class than please try follow code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.article { width: 200px; }
.btnNotes { }
.divNotes { display : none; }
</style>

<div class="main-div">
    <div class="article">
        <p>Text text Art 1  ... <button type="button" class="btnNotes" >Notes</button></p>
        <div class="divNotes">
            <p>Text text More 1</p>
            <p>Text text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="article">
        <p>Text text Art 2  ... <button type="button" class="btnNotes" >Notes</button></p>

        <div class="divNotes">
            <p>Text text More 2</p>
            <p>Text text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="article">
        <p>Text text Art 3  ...  <button type="button" class="btnNotes" >Notes</button></p>

        <div class="divNotes">
            <p>Text text More 3</p>
            <p>Text text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.btnNotes').click(function(){
            if ($(this).text() === "Notes") {
                $(this).text("Less");               
            } else {                
                $(this).text("Notes");              
            }
            $(this).parent().parent('div.main-div').find('div.divNotes').toggle();
        }); 
    });
</script>
```